# Is it possible to make multiple commands from one Flatpak app?

Tags: flatpak

For example, I have application with server and client, is it possible to create single Flatpak app called myapp, and after installing the application with:

```
flatpak install myapp
```

running it with something like:

```
flatpak run myapp.server
flatpak run myapp.client
```

And if it is possible can you show me please how to do it?
Or I have only option of creating separate applications for server and client?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is (currently) not possible to have two `command` inside one flatpak app.

But what you can do, is to create two distinct launchers:

`myapp.desktop` and `myapp.client.desktop`

(one of them **must** match the app-id!)

One with `Exec=/app/myapp` and  the other with `Exec=/app/myapp.client`